# How can stop a website (game) from refreshing when inactive

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I never did anything in Coding but this game i play refreshes every 3 min when inactive (spectating) i want to stop this or edit its script. It also refreshes when opening the DevTools in Chrome.

it script is external
`<script src="assets/js/new_main_out1.js?461"></script>`

```
window.lastDeath = Date.now()
window.playing = false

window.interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!window.playing) {
        if ((Date.now() - window.lastDeath) > 3*60*1000) {
            document.location.href = "https://game.com/landing/"
        }
    }
}, 10*1000)
```

Comment: open dev tools go into the console and type `clearInterval(interval)` which will stop the timer

Comment: thanks for commenting but the sites redirects to the landing and kicks out of game when opening the devtool (chrome) but it works in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continually reset `window.lastDeath` to within the last minute:

```
setInterval(() => {
  window.lastDeath = Date.now();
}, 60000);
```

You could also monkeypatch `window.setInterval` to detect if the page's function is passed, and if it is, ignore it (and start the interval normally otherwise).

Comment: wow thank you very much. i tried many things, i didn't think it would work. i just put your code in tampermonkey, thank you.